# How to conditionally add links using *ngIf in Angular2 to display links which have value

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-ng-if

I want to conditionally show the links only if it has value and I am not sure how to check that. I am making an API call and using that value to populate the data. I tried to filter with ngIf using 
`<a href="{{profil.FacebookUrl}}" *ngIf="profile.FacebookUrl != '' && profile.FacebookUrl != 'null' && profile.FacebookUrl != 'undefined'"</a>` 
but none of them seems to be working and I still see the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `*ngIF="profile.FacebookUrl"` should be enough.